# numpy.fft.fft() implementation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I am trying to obtain the spectrum of periodic signals using the `fft` function. Then plot the magnitude and phase of the transform. Magnitude plots are OK, but phase plots are completely unexpected. 
For example I used the functions Sin³(t) and Cos³(t). The code I have used is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.fft as nf
import math
import numpy as np
pi = math.pi

N=512

# Sin³(x)
t=np.linspace(-4*pi,4*pi,N+1);t=t[:-1]
y=(np.sin(t))**3
Y=nf.fftshift(nf.fft(y))/N
w=np.linspace(-64,64,N+1);w=w[:-1]

plt.figure("0")
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(w,abs(Y),'ro',lw=2)
plt.xlim((-4,4))
plt.ylabel(r"$|Y|$",size=16)
plt.title("Spectrum of sin\u00B3(t)")
plt.grid(True)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
ii=np.where(abs(Y)>1e-3)
plt.plot(w[ii],np.angle(Y[ii]),'go',lw=2)
plt.xlim((-4,4))
plt.ylabel(r"Phase of $Y$",size=16)
plt.xlabel(r"$\omega$",size=16)
plt.grid(True)

# Cos³(x)

t=np.linspace(-4*pi,4*pi,N+1);t=t[:-1]
y=(np.cos(t))**3
Y=nf.fftshift(nf.fft(y))/N
w=np.linspace(-64,64,N+1);w=w[:-1]

plt.figure("1")
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(w,abs(Y),'ro',lw=2)
plt.xlim((-4,4))
plt.ylabel(r"$|Y|$",size=16)
plt.title("Spectrum of cos\u00B3(t)")
plt.grid(True)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
ii=np.where(abs(Y)>1e-3)
plt.plot(w[ii],(np.angle(Y[ii])),'go',lw=2)
plt.xlim((-4,4))
plt.ylabel(r"Phase of $Y$",size=16)
plt.xlabel(r"$\omega$",size=16)
plt.grid(True)
```

The plots obtained are:

i) For Sin³(t) - 
[Magnitude and Phase of Spectrum of Sin³(t)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ5Ll.png)

ii) For Cos³(t) -
[Magnitude and Phase of Spectrum of Cos³(t)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eflim.png)

As You can see in the links above, The magnitude of Both functions are fine. The phase of Spectrum of Sin³(t) is correct as expected.

Since Cos³(t) is real and even, and expanding in terms of complex exponentials reveal that the Phase of the Coefficients is 0. But the plotted graph shows entirely different answer (see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eflim.png)): at w=-3 the phase is near 5 radians. What is the mistake I have done and what is the correct way to implement the FFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.fft` is behaving as expected; it's your plot which is causing the confusion. A call to `plt.tight_layout()` should help clear things up for you:

[image: Spectrum of cos t ^ 3]

If you take a careful look at the y-axis of the phase for cos³(t) you'll see that the values all have a 1e-17 prefactor. So at w = -3 the phase is **not** near 5 radians, it's actually near 5e-17 radians (which is for all intents and purposes zero).

I tidied up your code whilst I was looking into this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.fft as nf
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True

pi = np.pi
N = 512

t = np.linspace(-4*pi, 4*pi, N+1)[:-1]


def fft_func(x, func, N):
    y = func(x) ** 3
    Y = nf.fftshift(nf.fft(y)) / N
    w = np.linspace(-64, 64, N+1)[:-1]
    return y, Y, w


def plot_mag_phase(w, Y, func_name):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

    ii = np.where(abs(Y) > 1e-3)

    ax[0].plot(w, abs(Y), 'ro', lw=2)
    ax[1].plot(w[ii], np.angle(Y[ii]), 'go', lw=2)

    ax[0].set_xlim(-4, 4)
    ax[1].set_xlim(-4, 4)

    ax[0].set_ylabel("$|Y|$", size=16)
    ax[1].set_ylabel("Phase of $Y$", size=16)

    ax[0].set_title("Spectrum of {}\u00B3(t)".format(func_name))
    ax[1].set_xlabel(r'$\omega$', size=16)

    fig.tight_layout()

# sin x ^ 3
y, Y, w = fft_func(t, np.sin, N)
plot_mag_phase(w, Y, 'sin')

# cos x ^ 3
y, Y, w = fft_func(t, np.cos, N)
plot_mag_phase(w, Y, 'cos')
```

Comment: This is my first post in overflow , your answer gave me additional insights in plotting,and formatting, thanks a lot !

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad this was useful :) When you're coding you should try to avoid repeating the same / similar bits of code over and over. Instead, try to capture the logic you're using and implement it as some function or method.

Comment: Idk y but what is the relation between w and t , i.e. why w ranges from -64 to 64 ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why the range of `w` is -64 to 64, I only copied it from your code. Given that you set the x-limits of the plot to -4 -> 4,  you could drop the `w` altogether and use `plot_mag_phase(t, Y, 'sin')` for the same effect.